# Запятая в конструкции «но это если...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Согласна выручить. Но это*(**?**) *если никто другой не может.*
Нужна ли запятая? Или "это" в данном примере синонимично частице "только"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не ставится:

*Согласна выручить. Но **это если** никто другой не может.*

В даном случае местоимение ЭТО используется как **усилительная частица**.

Из словаря: 1. ЭТО. частица. 1. Усиливает вопросительное местоимение или наречие, а также **другие отдельные слова** в предложении.

Частица ЭТО в данном случае по значению близка к частице ТОЛЬКО. Она **указывает** на сказанное ранее (согласно выручить) и относится к союзу ЕСЛИ, **подчеркивая** условное значение сообщения.